# do not understand xml parsing code

Tags: android

the following code is for xml parsing.

```
try
{
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
final InputStream in = entity.getContent();
final SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
final XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
parser.parse(is, handler);
//TODO: get the data from your handler
}
catch (final Exception e)
{
Log.e("ParseError", "Error parsing xml", e);
}
```

over here where do i pass the url. 
also the response object in the line

response.getEntity() is an object of HttpResponse()?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is the processing after the url connection has been opened, and the result has been obtained. At this point there is no more url to pass.

`response` is the HttpResponse.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
Url url = new URL("http:// [and so on]");
XMLReader xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader();
xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```